# Fixed header is jumping and flickering when it's scrolled with iPhone/iOS

Tags: ios, css, scroll, css-position, mobile-safari

I tried to fix a bug related to scrolling in iOS.
Scrolling effect is applied to whole screen and there is a fixed header on the top.

The issue is that a fixed header is jumping and flickering when it's scrolled. This issue is only visible with iPhone/iOS. (I tested it with iPhone8, iOS12.2) and it's working perfectly with android device and desktop.

I already tried several workarounds like adding `-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;` and `-webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);` to the fixed element. I referred to similar issues found on Stackoverflow.[[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32875046/ios-9-safari-changing-an-element-to-fixed-position-while-scrolling-wont-paint/43188105#43188105)[[2]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37313872/vertical-scrolling-in-ios-not-smooth)

CSS is like the following.

```
.sidebar-mobile-transition {
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 0;
    background-color: white;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    overscroll-behavior: none;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow-x: auto;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}

.sidebar-mobile-header {
    top: 0;
    position: fixed;
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    background: black;
    color: white;
    z-index: 10;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
}
```

Is there any way to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having a fixed header and scrollable content doesn't work in iOS scrolling. I found out that we should use `position: absolute` instead of `position: fixed`.
Also we need to add `-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;` for content of sidebar.

It looks something like below..

```
.sidebar-mobile-header {
            top: 0;
            position: absolute;
            height: 50px;
            width: 100%;
            }

.sidebar-mobile-content {
            position: relative;
            overflow-y: scroll;
            overflow-x: hidden;
            -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
            height: 100%;
           }
```

Comment: How did you conclude this?